# How to kill process regardless whether it's 32 or 64-bit?

Tags: c#, process

In my tool at a certain point I want to kill a process by it's name. I'm testing now on Win7 64-bit, but the error I receive is:

> A 32 bit processes cannot access modules of a 64 bit process

Code:

```
Process[] runningProcesses = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (Process process in runningProcesses)
{
    // now check the modules of the process
    foreach (ProcessModule module in process.Modules)
    {
        if (module.FileName.Equals("communicator.exe"))
        {
            process.Kill();
        }
    }
}
```

I will have to use this tool on many computers (WinXP 32/64, Win7 32/64, Win8 64) and I need this tool to work on both type of architectures.
How to achieve this?

Comment: Can you privide some code?

Comment: The problem is not with killing the process, it's with trying to enumerate the modules of a process to determine if you want to kill it. You can't do that for a 64-bit process from your own 32-bit process as the message is telling you. How to solve the problem? No idea without a lot of detailed information about what you are trying to do.

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is to try using `process.ProcessName`. There's no way to make the iteration through the modules of a different-architecture work AFAIK.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.processname(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Is your own process 32 or 64 bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Process.GetProcessesByName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9.aspx), which will in most cases by identical to looking for the name of (main) module. You will still have to deal with the fact, that this will return multiple processes,so you may or may not want to kill all of them, but, YMMV.

```
foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcessesByName("communicator"))
{
    process.Kill();
}
```

Also note that the `Kill` method runs asynchronously, i.e. it may return before the respective process has actually been killed. You could add a `Process.WaitForExit()` if you care.

Answer (score 3):

It is **not** the Kill() call that fails, it is the foreach on process.Modules.  Which is very problematic in a 32-bit process when the target process is 64-bit, this doesn't get emulated perfectly in the Wow64 emulation layer.  That's surely a //TODO comment somewhere in the Windows source code with good odds that it just can't easily be implemented.

You'll have to make do with the Process.Name property.  Or change your project's Target platform setting in the Compile tab to AnyCPU so that you'll run as a 64-bit process as well.  Using the Modules property like you do doesn't otherwise make the code any safer, you are just as likely to kill the wrong process.

Comment: "//TODO comment" and "can't be implemented" are just ridiculous.  The [functions for querying 64-bit processes from 32-bit code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681408.aspx) and [specifically for module enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679316.aspx) are well documented.  The CLR must not be using them.

Comment: Shooting from the hip, as usual.  The CLR doesn't bother with implementation details like this.  It is implemented with pinvoke, NtQuerySystemInformation().  Famous for being an undocumented function that Microsoft was forced to "mention" as part of the DOJ settlement.  Why it struggles with 64-bit module enumeration is of course similarly undocumented and probably depends a great deal on the specific Windows version.

Comment: Still a shortcoming of the CLR, for calling an undocumented NTAPI call instead of the documented and working Win32 call, and not a problem with Windows.  And no I don't consider the "dbghelp.dll didn't ship with some Windows versions" to be a rationale.  The CLR could have shipped it, it wouldn't have made a dent in the overall footprint and most of dbghelp is probably duplicated in the CLR anyway.  I suppose the problem is that this isn't implemented in the CLR, even though it's heavily involved in process management, but as part of the BCL implementation.

Comment: Again, it is not the CLR.  There's just no point in bitching at me about this, I didn't write the code.  You are an MVP, work the available channels to send your bitch in the right direction.

Comment: But nothing stopped BCL from p/invoking the correct function.

Comment: I don't much care whether the `Process.Modules` property has this capability.  All these wrappers have worse limitations -- any serious task is going to interop to the APIs.  But your answer claims that Windows hasn't provided a way to do this, which is just wrong.

Comment: As an example of how the wrapper is busted, `ProcessModule` uses `IntPtr` for the `BaseAddress` property, among others.  It's the design of the BCL with the problem here, not Windows.