# How to end a process using C#

Tags: c#, process, windows-process

I am attempting to end a process in C#, the current code I have is this:

```
foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("chromedriver.exe"))
{
    process.Kill();
}
```

In Task manager, under processes the Image Name:

> chromedriver.exe *32

I am not ending the process... What is needed? or is this even possible?

Comment: Try this: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/803226/How-to-kill-process-by-process-name-and-user-name

Comment: did you try getting the process `chromedirver.exe *32`?

Comment: also, possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17024925/526704

Comment: @DLeh yes, I tried that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

'.exe' is not part of the process name, you just want:

```
foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("chromedriver"))
```

Comment: Make sure you are running under admin rights, was getting "access denied" when I tried this.